# Cordova background mode geo-location iOS 10

Tags: ios, cordova, ios10

In my cordova project I'm using a combination of Katzer's **cordova-plugin-background-mode** and Mauron85's **background-geolocation** plugins to enable location tracking in the background. Both plugins are the latest stable version.

This is working fine on android and ios 8, 9. But now with the release of **ios 10** we ran into a problem. I ran some tests and it seems that the background plugin is not consistently updating the mode (background or foreground) to the correct position. This makes our app very glitchy.

The code we use to enable / disable background mode looks like this:

```
    function enableBackgroundMode() {
        if ($rootScope.ionicReady && window.cordova && !cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.isEnabled()) {
            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
        }
    }

    function disableBackgroundMode() {
        if ($rootScope.ionicReady && window.cordova && cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.isEnabled()) {
            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disable();
        }
    }

    function isRunningInBackground() {
        return $rootScope.ionicReady && window.cordova && cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.isActive();
    }
```

When isRunningInBackground() is returning true, we call the following function to retrieve the user his location in the background.

```
function getCurrentLocationInBackground(interval) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  backgroundGeolocation.configure((location) => {
    backgroundGeolocation.finish();
    LogService.debug("Latitude: " + location.latitude + ", Longitude: " + location.longitude);
    deferred.resolve(location);
  }, (error) => {
    LogService.error('BackgroundGeoLocation error');
    deferred.reject(error);
  }, {
    desiredAccuracy: 10, //10m accurate
    stationaryRadius: 5, // if stationary, device must move beyond 5m to engage background-tracking
    distanceFilter: 5, //min distance a device must move before update event is generated
    stopOnTerminate: true, // <-- enable this to clear background location settings when the app terminates
    notificationTitle: translations['generic.background.tracking.title'],
    notificationText: translations['generic.background.tracking.text'],
    locationProvider: backgroundGeolocation.provider.ANDROID_ACTIVITY_PROVIDER,
    activityType: "AutomotiveNavigation",
    interval: interval ? parseInt(interval) : 30000
  });

  if (window.cordova) {
    backgroundGeolocation.start();
  }


  return deferred.promise;
}
```

However, on ios 10 if we put our app on the background, and return again to the foreground there is a big chance that cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.isActive() still is returning true which triggers our background logic..

I've been debugging this for a while now, but I can't see the problem.

Comment: i'm seeing this now too. Did you end up fixing it?

Comment: We ended up using another 3th party plugin that isn't free. I fear the support for the free plugins isn't there yet.

Answer (score -1):

This worked on ios10 for me.

Add this to your info.plist:

`<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
     <string>The app uses accelerometer to increase battery efficiency by intelligently toggling location-tracking</string>`